# In SceneKit, how do you make camera look at a specific face of a node's geometry?

Tags: scenekit

In SceneKit, you can add a lookAtConstraint constraint to your SceneView's Point Of View, to make Camera look at a certain node.

Is there a standard way of doing the same but for a specific face of a geometry?

So that, if I touch a specific face of a cube, camera would move so that the Z axis of the camera node gets in line with the normal of the touched face? So that the cube would look like a plane form the new perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

That would require movement of the camera, in addition to re-aiming it.

Imagine I'm in front of my house. I have a great view of the front and can just barely see the side to my left. In my Scene I tap the side of the house. A LookAt constraint would merely change the angle of the camera. It would not be aligned with the normal of that barely visible side.

To align with the normal, I'd have to walk around the house until I can stare at the house and be perpendicular to the side I tapped. At what radius? What path? You have to figure that out yourself.

Depending on what effect you're trying for, you might want to rotate the model instead of moving the camera. Rotate the tapped node locally (or as a child of an invisible parent) so that its minus-Z axis points out the tapped face, and keep a lookAtConstraint on the *node*, not the camera. This approach will change the look of the object, though: you will see it rotating, and the shading changing appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Hal, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> So that, if I touch a specific face of a cube, camera would move so that the Z axis of the camera node gets in line with the normal of the touched face?

Supposing you are using hit-testing to determine what object got touched, a [SCNHitTestResult](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnhittestresult) will give you both `localCoordinates` and `localNormal` from which it should be fairly easy to derive a camera transform.

One easy way would be to have the camera as a child node of the box, compute a position that would look like `localCoordinates + distance * localNormal` and finally a transform using [`GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/1409699-scnmatrix4fromglkmatrix4) and [`SCNMatrix4FromGLKMatrix4`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/1409699-scnmatrix4fromglkmatrix4).

Note that you can also use `worldCoordinates`, `worldNormal`, as well as conversion utilities such as [SCNNode.convertTransform(_:from:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1407996-converttransform).

Answer (score 0):

mutating on mnuages answer, use a hit test or ray trace to find where the user tapped on the mesh, then add a node at that location, and constrain the camera to lookAt that node.